# Blocking HTTP POST attack via mod_rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress site that is being attacked with the following HTTP POST requests:

```
x.x.x.x - - [15/Jul/2013:01:26:52 -0400] "POST /?CtrlFunc_stttttuuuuuuvvvvvwwwwwwxxxxxyy HTTP/1.1" 200 23304 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
x.x.x.x - - [15/Jul/2013:01:26:55 -0400] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 23304 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
```

The attack itself isn't bad enough to bring down Apache, but it does drive up the CPU usage more than I'd like it to. I would therefore like to block these using mod_rewrite -- straight to a 403 page should do it -- but I've not had any luck so far with anything I've tried. I would like to block all blank HTTP POST requests (to **/**) as well as **/?CtrlFunc_***

What I've done as a workaround for now is block all HTTP POST traffic but that won't work long-term.

Any ideas? I've invested several hours on this and have not made much progress.

Thanks!

Comment: please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694508/apache-linux-webserver-dynamically-block-incoming-post-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blocking the request via mod_rewrite, I'd use it as bait to record the IP of the offenders. Then, adding them to a 96 hour black list within your firewall will block all requests from them.

See [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Specifically, I believe that Fail2ban filters are the right place to start looking to write your url-specific case.

http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Filters

http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/HOWTO_apache_myadmin_filter

Comment: I have CSF installed - I wouldn't mind blocking the IPs completely. Can you suggest an easy way to pull the offending IP addresses and block them ("csf -d ipaddress" blocks them, I'm just not sure how to automate the process) - thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to combine the two applications... but here are some thoughts: https://forums.cpanel.net/f43/fail2ban-csf-conflicting-exim-purposes-333142.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a [Fail2ban blog post](http://klcollins.org/tag/fail2ban/) that creates a filter for this POST attack.